# Windows Backup Previous Versions after moving file?

Tags: windows-7, windows-backup, previous-versions

Let's say I set up Windows Backup to backup my pictures.  I know that down the road, I can look at the "Previous Versions" tab to restore a particular file back to an old copy.

*But*, suppose I have several previous versions of a file on my computer, and I move that file to a new subfolder (that is *still* under Windows Backup).  Will I still have access to previous versions of the file when it was in the old folder via "Properties?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this and it appears to work as expected: The file is in the "previous version" of the folder.

Please note that I used "restore point" and not backup, but the "magic" is basically the same anyway.